# Do events that occur "After the Activate Cylon Ships step" occur on revealed Cylon turns?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

Revealed Cylons can choose to enact Crisis cards from Caprica. At least one of these cards - *Fulfiller of Prophecy* - says something along these lines:

> After the Activate Cylon Ships step, return to the Resolve Crisis step [Draw a new Crisis card and resolve it.]

The rules state for a Cylon player's turn:

> There are no "Activate Cylon Ship" and "Prepare for Jump" steps during a revealed Cylon player's turn.

So, if a revealed Cylon uses this card, do we draw a new Crisis card or not? It's obvious the Activate Cylon Ships step doesn't happen, but it's not clear whether "*after* the step" occurs or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was apparently put to Fantasy Flight Games and their ruling was that the current player would simply discard the Crisis card and then resolve the top card of the Crisis deck (as instructed in the parenthesis).

(According to this link: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/398485/rule-question-revealed-cylon-caprica-and-fulfill)

I've only played BSG once and I was quite drunk at the time, so I'm hesitant to unpack things any further than that, but I hope this link is enough to settle your doubts!

Answer (score 0):

Crisis cards can be taken by human players, so the reasoning for the *After the Activate Cylon Ships step, return to the Resolve Crisis step [Draw a new Crisis card and resolve it.]* is that, if a human player draw that card, they must activate the cylon ships and return to the deck to take another one Crisis (and resolve it, what a mess...).

Since revealed Cylon don't have the Activate Cylon Ships Step, they will not trigger this effect. Just discard the card and take another one.